# Hard Drive keeps getting Corrupt Debian

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, debian

I have a Weird Problem with my Hard Drive.

First I had to use fsck in the "initramfs".

I thought it was just a force shutdown.

Then after a few days it happened again.

So I used Fsck and booted to Debian.

Then the file system went read only so I reboot and run fsck again in the initramfs.

Now Every time I Boot the System will go to read only mode.

I runned `fsck -f` but it did not Detect anything.

I only have a PXE Boot Server I use to install Debian and to repair using "Rescue Mode".

How can I check the Smart Status if I Can't install `smartctl` in the Debian System and the "Debian Installer Rescue Mode".

How can I Fix This.

EDIT 1:

Heres output from `smartctl -a`.

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [i686-linux-5.10.25-1.0-lts] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Blue
Device Model:     WDC WD5000AAKX-75U6AA0
Serial Number:    WD-WMC2E0785487
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 003642a90
Firmware Version: 19.01H19
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu May  6 19:56:58 2021 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 8460) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  86) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3037) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       4
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   153   141   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3325
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3053
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       6475
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2844
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       965
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2098
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   106   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       6093
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       17960947086
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       39242396778

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      6474         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      6473         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6473         -
# 4  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      6473         -
# 5  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      6473         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6471         -
# 7  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      6471         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5834         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5731         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5731         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5722         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5676         -
#13  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5631         -
#14  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      5614         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5611         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5596         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5595         -
#18  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      80%      5588         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5530         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5524         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5480         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a failing drive. Install a resuce environment (such as [SystemRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue.org/)) into your PXE Boot Server and boot that to use `smartctl`

Then you can do the usual `smartctl -a /dev/sdX` for an appropriate value of `X`.

---

The disk now looks fine, so the next thing to check is memory. See if you can boot the `memtest86+` tool and have that check the system's RAM

Comment: I runned  ```smartctl``` and it reported no errors. Is it safe to test if the hard drive works in the System Rescue environment.

Comment: Your question seemed to be asking how to install and run `smartctl`. Please add its results into your question unless you are 100% completely sure you understand what it's telling you

Comment: I edited the Question.

Comment: I tested the RAM with 3 Passes and it had 235 errors found. Do you think the RAM might be the cause for the Corruption of the Hard Drive.

Comment: Yes, almost certainly